# Waf generating Visual Studio projects?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, build-process, waf

Can the [Waf](http://code.google.com/p/waf/) build system generate Visual Studio project files for C/C++?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

An "extra" tool does now (check waflib/extras/msvs.py).

Since this is used by the waf author, I think you can rely on it.

Answer (score 8):

-- A few years passed... --

I didn't try it (I'm learning about Waf right now) but it seems it can :

> IDE support: Eclipse, Visual Studio and Xcode project generators
>   (waflib/extras/)

Source : http://code.google.com/p/waf/

The generator script is readable there, with the project template that you can see : http://code.google.com/p/waf/source/browse/waflib/extras/msvs.py

Also, some maybe related docs : http://docs.waf.googlecode.com/git/apidocs_16/tools/msvc.html

I'm checking if it works today right now.

Answer (score 3):

No, waf does not support this at this time but nothing stops you from calling the vcbuild from waf if you want.

Comment: No, see the other answers :)